# How to import data from external mysql db into a Symfony2 Project?

Tags: mysql, symfony, import, doctrine-orm

I'm developping a new version of my website with Symfony2.
I used mysql on the previous version and now I use Doctrine2/Mysql.
I want to import my User Table into the new version. I think that the best way is to use the command tool provided by Symfony2.

However, I don't know how to browse my old mysql database (or mysql dump) in order to execute php script to populate my new database.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it !

I don't know if that is the best solution but it works.

1) Import the old table in my new database

2) Ask Doctrine to introspect the database and generate the corresponding metadata files.

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

3) Ask Doctrine to import the schema and build related entity classes by executing the following command

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation
```

Now, I can use this EntityManager on my old database to do all the scripts I want.

You can find more information here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a new database, you can keep using the actual one. But if you ever want duplicate it, you can use the [*mysqladmin* command tool](http://www.rubyrobot.org/article/duplicate-a-mysql-database).
Then, you can [generate your entities from your database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html).

Comment: The database schema is completely different. I need to browse all the data, manipulate it and populate my news db by using php script like `$user = new User('username');` and `persistAndFlush($user)`

Comment: In this case, you can setup two entity managers to use both your old and new database, and with a Symfony2 task, fetch all the data from the old one, and save it into the new one. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html -- I wonder if that can be done using a SQL script though.

Comment: My old website is not a Symfony2 project so I have not entityManager on it. It's just my problem. I need to browse a sql dump in my symfony2 command tool.

Comment: You only need the second entityManager to access your old database. Then you should be able to fetch the data from your old database with [native SQL queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) and map them with addScalarResult() into an array. I haven't tested it, but it may be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds tricky enough to be an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) problem.  There are a number of [tools](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-etl) out there; many enterprise though a few dual licensed open source.  If you're only doing this once, then many of the tools may be overly complex.  If you have to do this kind of data munging often, however, then a good ETL app can be a huge time saver.  I can recommend Altova's [MapForce](http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html) as one of the more straightforward and intuitive.  It's Windows-only though.

Comment: Yes. The solution is a kind of ETL but I will use it just only once. So I think that is not necessery to use a ETL solution. Too much learning, configuration for just an import. I'm watching for create an entityManager on my old database.